# How to get the case owner name?

Tags: apex, soql, case, owner

You can see in the example below that I'm using the OwnerId to check who's the owner of the case (it isn't pretty but it works).

But what if I have 100 users? Can someone suggest a solution for this?

```
List < Case > listOfCases = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE RecordTypeId IN: setRecordTypeIds];
for (Case c: listOfCases) {
    if (c.OwnerId == '005w0000004CjwgAAC') {
        //do something....
    }
}
```

Is there a way to query the case owner name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should filter on a unique field, so I would avoid using `Name`. You can pull in fields like `Username`, `Alias`, etc. through your query using a [`Right Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join):

```
SELECT Owner.Username FROM Case
```

Comment: I tried to run it and this is the output I got:
15:52:50:010 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|Case:{OwnerId=00G20000001Wa8AEAS, Id=500w000000mYBkwAAG, RecordTypeId=01220000000FffjAAC}

Can't see Owner.Username?

Comment: You can't get it by debugging the object itself. You would have to debug `c.Owner.Username`. @Dante

Comment: I executed an anonymous window with the following:
Case c = [SELECT Owner.Name FROM Case Limit 1];
system.debug(c);
And then I got the output I posted above

Comment: @Dante I know. I'm saying when you `debug(c)` you're at the mercy of what Salesforce decides to log. When you `debug(c.Owner.Username)` you get exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Now I get it :)